# Change background color of list item in listview when it is selected

Tags: android, listview

How can i  Change background color of list item in listview when it is selected.

In res/drawable folder i have create listselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" /> 
</selector>
```

then in values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <drawable name="focused">#ff5500</drawable>
    <drawable name="selected">#FF00FF</drawable>

</resources>
```

This is listview.xml

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
         >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

but it is not changing the background color of list item when selected...

Comment: Look here. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ Althought its older, there is implementiation of custom color on items click. I think it has to do something with android:drawable. Try to use android:color.

Answer (score 2):

There's no link between your ListView and it's selector. You need to add the following line of code to your `listview.xml`.

```
android:listSelector=“@drawable/listselector"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).  Althought its older, there is implementiation of custom color on items click. I think it has to do something with android:drawable. Try to use

```
android:color="@color/yourcolor"
```

And put your drawables to colors:

```
<color name="focused">#ff5500</color>
<color name="selected">#FF00FF</color>
```

Its in /res/values/colors folder.